# Chartjs : Y axis starting with highest datapoint

Tags: html, chart.js

I am building a line graph using ChartJs and want to start the Y-axis with the highest number available in my data object and end with the lowest number

eg: data: [8, 8, 9, 7, 7, 7, 5,4] 
I want 9 to be shown at the bottom left and at 4 to be at the top.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scale overwriting:

```
    new Chart(cnv.getContext("2d")).Line(data, {
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleStartValue: 4,
        scaleStepWidth: 1,
        scaleSteps: 4,
    });
```

This will produce `4,5,6,7,8` Y axis (Please note, you have to implement start point and steps number/width calculation)

Comment: I have one more question, is there a way to show non numbers on the Y-axis for eg: a,b,c instead of 1,2,3?..thanks

Comment: There is a `scaleLabel` option, use like `scaleLabel: "Current value: <%=value%>"` but some workaround needed to make it show dynamic data.

Comment: I tried using scaleLabel and it's not working..check this out..http://jsfiddle.net/1xq2q56w/